# Replace a certain values in rows using other column values as reference

Tags: dataframe, julia

I need to replace certain values in the `bw` column using `id` as the reference. I need to replace all the `0` values with the values found in the first row of each id.

**Data**

```
df = DataFrame(id=["Mouse","Mouse","Mouse","Mouse","Rat","Rat","Rat","Rat"],
               time=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
               bw=[25,0,0,0,100,0,0,0]) 

julia> df
8×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ id     │ time  │ bw    │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ Mouse  │ 1     │ 25    │
│ 2   │ Mouse  │ 2     │ 0     │
│ 3   │ Mouse  │ 3     │ 0     │
│ 4   │ Mouse  │ 4     │ 0     │
│ 5   │ Rat    │ 1     │ 100   │
│ 6   │ Rat    │ 2     │ 0     │
│ 7   │ Rat    │ 3     │ 0     │
│ 8   │ Rat    │ 4     │ 0     │
```

**OUTPUT required:**

```
df_out = DataFrame(id=["Mouse","Mouse","Mouse","Mouse","Rat","Rat","Rat","Rat"],
                   time=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   bw=[25,25,25,25,100,100,100,100]) 
 

julia> df_out
8×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ id     │ time  │ bw    │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ Mouse  │ 1     │ 25    │
│ 2   │ Mouse  │ 2     │ 25    │
│ 3   │ Mouse  │ 3     │ 25    │
│ 4   │ Mouse  │ 4     │ 25    │
│ 5   │ Rat    │ 1     │ 100   │
│ 6   │ Rat    │ 2     │ 100   │
│ 7   │ Rat    │ 3     │ 100   │
│ 8   │ Rat    │ 4     │ 100   │
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `transform` on `GroupedDataFrame`

```
julia> transform(groupby(df, :id), :bw => first => :bw)
8×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ id     │ time  │ bw    │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ Mouse  │ 1     │ 25    │
│ 2   │ Mouse  │ 2     │ 25    │
│ 3   │ Mouse  │ 3     │ 25    │
│ 4   │ Mouse  │ 4     │ 25    │
│ 5   │ Rat    │ 1     │ 100   │
│ 6   │ Rat    │ 2     │ 100   │
│ 7   │ Rat    │ 3     │ 100   │
│ 8   │ Rat    │ 4     │ 100   │
```